# How to code to skip a shapefile, if it doesn't exist?

Tags: arcpy

So if shapefile 'AAA010' does not exist, how can I skip the Merge and Clip and move on to the next part of the script? If possible I would like to keep the current script as it is, but by just adding else or if, Sorry still trying to learn the ins and outs.

```
import os, fnmatch, arcpy


arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\DataMagement\Comp_3\SA_MGCP3.gdb'  
fcMerged = 'MergedFeatureClass'
fcClipped = 'fcClipped'
fcToClip = r'C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\DataMagement\Country.shp'

filesMatched = list()

for root, subfolders, files in os.walk (r'C:\Users\sysadmin\Desktop\DataMagement\MGCP_Raw'):

    for f in fnmatch.filer(files, 'AAA010.shp'):     
        filesMatched.append(os.path.join(root,f))

    if filesMatched:
        print ' files found - merging'
        arcpy.Merge_management (filesMatched, fcMerged)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis (fcMerged, fcToClip,fcClipped)

    else:
         print 'nothing found - skipping'
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of code duplicated in what you have posted.  As much as possible try to post code snippets which illustrate just the part of *your* code where *you* are stuck.  Your title does this well but then you've just given us what looks like a code dump.  This is very near a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79845/validating-whether-shapefile-exists-using-arcpy

Comment: I have at least three possible interpretations of what you're trying to do. 1) You don't want to process the merge/clip on the AAA010 shapefiles if even one of the searched subdirectories does not contain an AAA010.shp--though it may be found in every other directory; 2) if AAA010.shp is not found in a given subdirectory, you instead want to search in that directory for LAQ075.shp and then merge it with all the other AAA010.shps from other directories; 3) if no AAA010.shp files are found in any of the directories, you obviously don't want to try merging the nonexistent files in an empty list.

Comment: Could you clarify which of those three options--or some other option--you are trying for?

Comment: Also, you have a couple recurring typos in your code: filer -> filter, py -> arcpy

Comment: @Tom - I would like to skip the 'AAA010.shp' all together and move on to the next shapefile if that shapefile does not exist. So skip the merge and clip.

Comment: @BrianJ, scenario 1 or 3 from my comment above? They both skip the merge/clip.

Comment: @Tom scenario 3. Thanks for your help also, I really appreciate it

Comment: Brian, since it's on hold, I can't post an answer here, but here's a link to some code that should work: http://pythonfiddle.com/help-for-brian-j

Comment: @Tom. Thanks, I will try it tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tom I just had a quick question for what you sent. If there is not value 'AAA010', what happens? Will it go on to what I write after from what you sent?

Comment: @Tom the question is only on hold because its asker has not updated it with any of the clarifications you requested.  I'm hoping he will review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 to see how the question improvement process is designed to work.

Comment: @PolyGeo Hopefully that cleared somethings up. Sorry for being a pain

Comment: `py.Merge_management` and `fnmatch.filer`will throw errors - any code snippet presented should be run to make sure that any errors (hopefully only one) they throw is at the focus of the question.

Comment: @PolyGeo When I run the code above, it works exactly how it should. I run into an error though when I run the code for another shapefile, for example 'ASL010' and the 'ASL010' does not exist in the directories. So I am trying to find a way, that if 'ASL010' does not exist, I can skip the merge and clip and move on to the next set of data.

Comment: @BrianJ Which code hits an error: as you have it posted above or as I wrote it in the link above?

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [**Exists**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/exists.htm) `arcpy.Exists()`

```python
YourShapefile = "pathtoshapefile.shp"

if arcpy.Exists(YourShapefile):
    # put your code here to run on the shapefile
else:
    print "Shapefile {} doesn't exist".format(YourShapefile)
```

**EDIT:**
Now that I understand what you're asking, try this for your **`arcpy.merge`**:

```
if filesMatched: # Checks to see if files exist in filesMatched
    print "files found - merging"
    arcpy.Merge_management (filesMatched, fcMerged)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis (fcMerged, fcToClip, fcClipped)
else:
    print "nothing found - skipping"
```

Comment: Where in the script would this fit in? And my pathtosshapefile is a little difficult since there are 100s of the same name for the shapefile, just in different folders and subfolders.

Comment: I've updated.  Please try to include all the info you posted in your comments above in your actual question rather than as comments.  You can edit your question and add all the details and any error messages.

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately, it didn't grab all the files in the directory and tried to loop then failed. Any suggestions

Comment: If the rest of your script doesn't work, I suggest you ask a new separate question with all the relevant details, script, and error messages.